# FAB native-base is not displaying under the Flatlist-renderItem

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, native-base

**I want to display multiple FAB based on numColumns**
*Unable to render the FAB object inside the Flatlist*

```
 <View style={styles.search_field_container}>
              <FlatList
                data={formatData(this.state.users, numColumns)}
                numColumns={numColumns}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                renderItem={({item}) => this.renderitem(item)}
              />
```

---

```
renderitem = item => {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Fab
            active={this.state.active}
            direction="up"
            containerStyle={{ }}
            style={{ backgroundColor: '#5067FF' }}
            position="bottomRight"
            onPress={() => this.setState({ active: !this.state.active })}>
            <Icon name="share" />
            <Button style={{ backgroundColor: '#34A34F' }}>
              <Icon name="logo-whatsapp" />
            </Button>
            <Button style={{ backgroundColor: '#3B5998' }}>
              <Icon name="logo-facebook" />
            </Button>
            <Button disabled style={{ backgroundColor: '#DD5144' }}>
              <Icon name="mail" />
            </Button>
          </Fab>
        </View>
      </Container>
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: I am able to render multiple FAB using forEach / map function

Comment: what does ```formatData``` do?

Comment: Thats the function returning the list of JSON objects

Comment: if the function returns an empty array, flatlist won't render.

Comment: Yes, thats right , In Metro bundler I have verified it has data of size 2. So expected is FlatList to renderItems of 2 FAB object

Comment: I've created an excample here https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/nativebase---example and it's working.

Comment: please add code for  ```formatData``` function and the structure of ```this,state.users```

Comment: @JuniusL. Let me try with the code . formatData is the API call..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207895/discussion-between-pavan-and-junius-l).